# Encrypt a partition shared between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, windows, encryption

Currently, I have NTFS-partitions which are shared between Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11 Pro. Some of them I'd like to encrypt. I could use BitLocker on Windows but then it is not possible to access the partitions in Ubuntu. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html). With this, you can encrypt a part of an NTFS disk.

It's a continuation of TrueCrypt, it's open source, and it's available for both Linux and Windows.

The easiest way to install VeryCrypt on Ubuntu is to add the PPA `unit193` which contains VeraCrypt:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/encryption
```

After that, run `apt update` and install VeraCrypt:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install veracrypt
```